# Turning off trackbacks & comments

Tags: comments

We have a few different websites running various versions of Wordpress that have comments and trackbacks turned off, yet I still receive emails saying there's some waiting for me!

I've turned them both off in the admin area and also removed the comments box completely yet I still get them, how can I fully turn them off?

Comment: What is senders email address.. is it same as your wordpress email id?

Comment: @VinodDalvi It's from the default email address in the admin.

Comment: I posted this few hours ago http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89236/disable-wordpress-comments-api/89238#89238 - you could try this method to turn the comments off.

Comment: @Rob Is the solution provided by birgie working for you?

Comment: @birgire Ok that sorts comments, what about trackbacks (probably more annoying than comments!)?

Comment: @birgire and VinodDalvi the question is not only about comments, the solution provided by birgire won't prevent trackbacks posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent comments receiving add following line to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
```

And to prevent trackbacks receiving just add this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'pings_open', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Ok that sorts comments, what about trackbacks (probably more annoying than comments!)?

Comment: @Rob I have updated my answer