# Disable comments

Tags: comments, comment-form

I'm wondering if there's any way to prevent users from leaving comments but still display the comments form? So, whenever a new comment is posted, it should be automatically trashed or it shouldn't be added at all.

The comment form I have is for presentational purposes only and it shouldn't accept any comments but it should be displayed.

I've already found `preprocess_comment` and `comment_post` hooks but I'm out of ideas on how to utilize that to block commenting. I'm thinking about something like:

```
function prefix_delete_comments( $comment_id ) {
  wp_delete_comment( $comment_id, true );
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'prefix_delete_comments');
```

but will this work or will it cause some errors in later execution?

Comment: You can try [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89238/26350) if you want to disable comments but still want to have the comment form visible.

Answer (score 0):

(copied from comment above, so that this question will get an answer):

You can try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89238/26350 if you want to disable comments but still want to have the comment form visible. – birgire Oct 24 '13 at 1:46